# Anticipate vs Expect

Tags: word-usage

What is the difference between these two sentences:

> The **expected** result meant that he **anticipated** winning $100.
>   The **anticipated** result meant that he **expected** to win $100.

Both mean **waited for something in the future**, but...?

Comment: Related: [What is the difference between “anticipate” and “expect”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/111885/what-is-the-difference-between-anticipate-and-expect)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both *expect* and *anticipate* can be used of a future event to mean, approximately, that you believe it is probable or certain that it will happen. That's the meaning of both terms in both of your sentences.

*Anticipate*, however, can also be used with a different meaning: to perform some action **before** some future event occurs. For instance:

> Huygens may have **anticipated** Newton's distinction between mass and weight. ... *That is, Huygens may have had the idea of distinguishing mass and weight before Newton did*.
>
> The bankrupt had **anticipated** his income by nearly one year's receipts. ... *That is, the bankrupt spent nearly an entire year's income before he received it.*
>
> In May, 1803, the British government **anticipated** Bonaparte's attack by a declaration of war. ... *That is, the British disrupted Bonaparte's plans by declaring war before Bonaparte was ready to attack.*